# Find the general solution to the second-order differential equation $y''=f(y')$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is only known that $f$ is continuously differentiable and depends only on $y'$.
On the one hand, finding the general solution to this equation doesn't seem hard. After substitution $p=y'$, I just solve it as a separable one:

$y''=f(y')$

$p=\int_{}^{}f(p)dx$

$y'=\int_{}^{}f(y')dx$

And after that I am once again tempted to just solve it as a separable one:

$y=\iint_{}^{}f(y')dx^2$

However, it just feels illegal to integrate since we do not know much about the function $f$. So, is it possible to solve such equations like that and if yes, does it always work?

Comment: It might be worth adding that for any root $u_0$ of $f$, the constant function $u(x) = u_0$ is a solution to the equation in $u$, hence $y(x) = u_0 x + C$ is a solution to the original o.d.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have $y'(x) = a + \int_0^x f(y'(s)) \mathrm{d}s$ from solving $u' = f(u)$ for $u := y'$ and $a := y'(0)$ (thanks to Picard-Lindelöf and $f$ being $\mathcal{C}^1$, $y$ exists at least locally), you can integrate once more since both sides are continuous and thus integrable on every compact $[0,t]$, to get:
$$y(t) = b + at + \int_0^t\left(\int_0^xf(y'(s))\mathrm{d}s\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
where $b := y(0)$. Notice the $at$ part that didn't appear in your findings due to not taking integration constants into account.
(I used $0$ for the initial conditions but you can replace it with anything else.)

Comment: The solution is expressed in terms of the unknown $y'(s)$?

Comment: @enzotib To my knowledge you can't really give an explicit formula for the solution in general, the best you can do for unspecified $f$ is to have an implicit formula like here and justify the existence of a function verifying this with Picard-Lindelöf or other theorems.

Answer (score 2):

If we set $u=y'$, the variables separate
\begin{align*}
& u' = f(u) \\
& \frac{u'}{f(u)} = 1 \\
& \int \frac{du}{f(u)} = t + C 
\end{align*}
If we set
$$
F(u) = \int \frac{du}{f(u)}
$$
and if we suppose it is invertible, we have
\begin{align*}
& u = F^{-1}(t+C) \\
& y = C' + \int F^{-1}(t+C)dt
\end{align*}